# GNOME Classic bottom bar transparency

Tags: gnome-classic, gnome-tweak-tool, transparency, gnome-tweaks

So I am using the GNOME classic shell, I have been able to make the top bar transparent using the Dynamic Panel Transparency in gnome tweaks, but I hate that the bottom bar does not match and is still solid white. Is there a way to make that match?

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm using Pop!OS, I don't think DPT works yet in 20.04. I might be wrong though because I haven't tried it in Ubuntu.